# Selenium Webdriver unable to give JavaScript popup window handle

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have one web page page where there is an button which when get clicked, popup an window form, where i have to select some values. I am currently using IE browser and selenium 2.53 libraries to automate this flow. Now my problem is that i am unable to switch to this popup window since i am not getting any window handle and every time it is showing only one parent handle.

I have tried alert/popup switch also but still this popup as invoked via a button from the parent page are not recognizable and so unable to do any action in this pop up page.

```
Set<String> winhandle= driver.getWindowHandles();
    System.out.println(winhandle);
    for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) 
    {
        System.out.println(handle); 

        String newURL = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(newURL); 
      }
```

Regards,
Nir

Answer (score 0):

In your code you never actually iterate over the other windows.

In order to correctly print the handles of all the windows (including the popup), try to modify your code:

```
Set<String> winhandle = driver.getWindowHandles();
for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    driver.switchTo().window(handle);  // This line was missing. It tells the driver to operate on a different window
    System.out.println(handle); 
}
```

And then - after testing - you can just break the loop whenever you're in the right window.

Does this work for you?

Comment: Not sure. But I have iterate to know whether my  driver captured the popup window correctly or not. But every time I get only one parent window browser handle and not the popup browser window. So until I don't know what is the handle name of my popup window, I cannot switchTo to that window.

Comment: You didn't get the other windows because you repeatedly tried to print the same window's handle. Try to apply the code I've posted and let me know if it worked

Comment: Thanks..i have tried  your code but still getting handle one only instead of 2 handle name: driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); 
  
  Set<String> winhandle= driver.getWindowHandles();  
  for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
      driver.switchTo().window(handle);  // This line was missing. It tells the driver to operate on a different window
      System.out.println(handle); 
  }

Comment: Try to print `winhandle.size()` to see if the browser did open another window, or maybe the problem is somewhere else

Comment: Tried but giving count =1. This popup window is getting invoked by below  html code (parent):-<input type="button" id="PICKER_postid" name="PICKER_postid" value="..." onclick="javascript:showPostPicker();">

Comment: In additional to this i have reached parent controls (which popup child) by using below framewswitch:  WebElement fr = driver.findElement(By.id("asp_frame"));
  driver.switchTo().frame(fr);  
  driver.switchTo().frame("main_iframe");     ----->Do i need to switch back to  default contents to get the popup window handle?

Answer (score 0):

Its strange but now true that same code using the window handles and switchTO is working fine with the chrome browser and it was not working for the IE browser. I don't know how to fix it in the IE browser but working great in the chrome browser.

regards,
Nir